# How to calculate Center and Enpoint of an Arc, that starts and ends in a tangent?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

While developing a gear generator I ran into a problem that seems more difficult than expected. The sides of a tooth should be connected to the bottom of the root via an arc. This arc should start in a tangent and end in a tangent. The following picture should visualize the requirement.

[The tooth and its root fillets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKdh9.png)

The radius of the arc should be dependent on the radius of the root circle $R_1$. $R_2$ is the radius of the base circle where the tooth ends. The starting point $Ps$ is known. I would like to calculate the center of the arc $Pc$ and the endpoint $Pe$.

[The problem hopefully reduced to it's possible solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C5In.png)

I hope this all makes enough sense. I tried to find a triangle to calculate this with simple trigonometry, but either I'm just not able to see it or the problem is really more difficult than expected.

Many Greetings!
Remo

PS: I don't seem to be allowed to embed pictures. This makes posting the problem in the format I intended quite impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let us set $d=P_CP_S$.

Application of Pythagoras' theorem to right triangle $OP_CP_S$ where $0$ is the common center of the two circles gives:

$$(R_1+d)^2=d^2+R_2^2$$

yielding

$$d=\dfrac{R_2^2-R_1^2}{2R_1}$$

Comment: (Perhaps also add $\theta = \angle P_s O P_c$, and remind that $\tan\theta = \frac{d}{R_2}$?  It's obvious, though.)

Comment: @Glärbo You are right in the fact that angle $\theta$ is maybe as important as $d$ for the OP.

Comment: Many thanks for the help! I had feared it's something as obvious as that. It's a bit embarrassing, really. Well, there are days where you just don't get the solution yourself.

Comment: Why embarassing ? We have all experienced that...